# remote host ssh login fail python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to login to remote host(ssh) by using python script but it fails with below error:

My Code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import pxssh
 import getpass
 try:
     s = pxssh.pxssh()
     hostname = raw_input ('hostname: ')
     username = raw_input('username: ')
     password = geenter code here`tpass.getpass('password: ')
     s.login (hostname, username, password)
     s.sendlin`enter code here ('en force')
     s.prompt()enter code here
     print s.before
     s.logout()
 except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
     print "pxssh failed on login."
     print str(e)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 193, in login
    spawn._spawn(self, cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 514, in _spawn
    command_with_path = which(self.command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1782, in which
    pathlist = string.split (p, os.pathsep)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'split'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 18, in <module>`
    import problem_report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/multipart.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    import email.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/charset.py", line 14, in <module>
    import email.quoprimime
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/quoprimime.py", line 48, in <module>
    from string import hexdigits
ImportError: cannot import name hexdigits

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.login (hostname, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pxssh.py", line 193, in login
    spawn._spawn(self, cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 514, in _spawn
    command_with_path = which(self.command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1782, in which
    pathlist = string.split (p, os.pathsep)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Is there anything that need to be changed on the `pxssh` file in the python?

Comment: You forgot the error! And you don't need all those backticks.

Comment: Error added now. without this back ticks does not allow me to post question :-(